# Batch file: Using of command "FOR" for the appointment of two variables

Tags: windows, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

The question is: how to assign two variables to perform the function?

For example I have something like this:

```
for %f in *.pdf do PDF2TXT -"%f" -fast -t "%f.txt"
```

as you can see, `%f` - is a variable name of every pdf file in the derictory

But I need to include 2 variables something like this:

```
for %f in *.pdf and for %g in *.rtf do PDF2TXT -"%f" -"%g" -merge -fast -t "%f.txt"
```

How make it work?

THANKS!

Best regards,
Eugene Evtushenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %f in (*.pdf) do for %g in (%~nf.rtf) do PDF2TXT -"%f" -"%g" -merge -fast -t "%~nf.txt"
```

`FOR` syntax is `for %x in (list) do`

applying the `~n` operator to the metavariable (`%f` in your case) selects just the name part of the filename in `%f`. See `FOR /? |more` from the prompt for more info.

You don't say what you mean by `"work"`. It's a meaningless term in this context. We can't read your mind.

This routine will for all `.pdf` files, select the matching *name*.rtf and perform `PDF2TXT` on some combination of whatever the names are, evidently producing *name*.txt. Without an explicit explanation of what you want to do, we have to assume - that's very dangerous.

It would probably be easier to try

```
for %f in (*.pdf) do PDF2TXT -"%f" -"%~nf,rtf" -merge -fast -t "%~nf.txt"
```

which would do the same thing.

Comment: Dear Magoo! Thank you very much. I'll try it today and I will make report about results! Eugene Evtushenko